# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. when add docs to index

Tags: solrnet

when i add docs to index, the page returns 400 bad request. And the solr has been start up and can get data from database. So i need put the data into index. However, it's failed always.

---

1) Here is code snippet of SolrBaseRepository

```
/// <summary>    
/// Base repository for Solr    
/// </summary>  
public class SolrBaseRepository  
{    
    /// <summary>    
    /// New instance of Solr    
    /// </summary>    
    /// <typeparam name="T">Specific type</typeparam>  
    public class Instance<T>    
    {    
        /// <summary>  
        /// Start Solr instance for a specific type  
        /// </summary>  
        public void Start()  
        {  
            var instances = Startup.Container.GetAllInstances(typeof (ISolrOperations<T>));  

            if (instances.Count() == 0)  
            {  
                Startup.Init<T>(Toolbox.SolrUrl);  
            }  
        }  

    }  
}
```

2) here is main part of schemal.xml

```
<fields>    
    <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />   
    <field name="firstname" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false"required="false" />   
    <field name="lastname" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="position" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />  
    <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />  
</fields>  
<copyField source="firstname" dest="text" />    
<copyField source="lastname" dest="text" />    
<copyField source="position" dest="text" />    
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>    
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>    
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND" />
```

3) solrurl: `http://localhost:8080/solr`

```
<appSettings>  
<add key="SolrUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/solr"/>  
</appSettings>
```

4) error is here:

```
/// <summary>  
/// Add all players to the index  
/// </summary>  
public void IndexPlayers()  
{  
    new SolrBaseRepository.Instance<Player>().Start();  

    var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Player>>();  
    var players = new PlayerRepository().GetPlayers();  

    **solr.Add(players);** // The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.   
    solr.Commit();  
}
```

Comment: new SolrBaseRepository.Instance<Player>().Start(); var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Player>>(); var specificPlayer = new PlayerRepository().GetPlayer(player.FirstName, player.LastName, player.Position); solr.Add(specificPlayer); solr.Commit();

Comment: please post the code in the question, properly formatted. Also post the definition of SolrBaseRepository.

Comment: also post the definition of Player and your schema.xml.

Answer (score 5):

The solr log would give you the info that you need, or if you opened from console there should be an exception throw to the console.

Answer (score 3):

Look at Tomcat log file, it contains detailed Solr exception. On my machine it's located at

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs

You'll find a file named in the format catalina..log. (e.g. catalina.2011-05-26.log)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

- Comment all /dataimport blocks in solrconfig.xml
- Make sure ProtocolVersion is HttpVersion.Version10 (the Post method in SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection). If not, download the SolrNet source and re-compile with your preference.

Comment: Did you experience any problem that motivated you to switch to HttpVersion.Version10 ? I'd like to hear about that.

Comment: I read that switching to HttpVersion.Version10 would help. I think what helped me tho, was checking that the solrconfig.xml was well-formed.